# Shortening this script as much as possible using wildcard/regex/code golfing

Tags: powershell

I have made a short script that will pull dns txt records down from a server and combine them into a single string.
DNS txt records are:

`1.website.com`
`2.website.com`
`3.website.com`

each of these are iterated through using the single digit number.
the double quotes at the beginning and the end of the strings are trimmed
This works exactly as I would like it too
I am simply interested in seeing how short I can get it
assistance is appreciated please and thank you

```
$i = 1
1..2 | foreach {
$w="$i.website.com"
sv -N v -Va ((nslookup -q=txt $w )[-1]).Trim().Trim('"')
$p += "$v"
$i += 1
}
```

and ideally i'd like to return the $p variable, that being the concatenated string

Comment: You could do `$p+=1..3|%{Resolve-DnsName "$_.website.com." -Ty TXT -EA 0|% Strings}`

Comment: Sooooo close, but this still has a space between each string to concatenate

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what that means. You can type `$p` as `[string]` or assign an empty string to it up front if you want string concatenation rather than array output

Comment: If the first dns record is `aaa` and the second is `bbb` this code results in `aaa bbb` instead of `aaabbb`. There is a space between entries.

Comment: Ahh, you're talking about the _output_ length, I thought your question was about golfing the code. Assuming `$p` is nonexisting or contains $null or an empty string at the start of executing this code, simply move the `$p+=` operation into the foreach block: `1..3|%{$p+=...}`

Comment: ```1..3|%{p+=Resolve-DnsName "$_.website.com." -Ty TXT -EA 0|% Strings}```?

Comment: You're missing the `$`

Comment: Also wanna add it as an answer so I can accept it and give you proper credit?

Comment: ```Missing expression after '.' in pipeline element```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of obvious consolidations you can make here, most notably the fact that neither `$i` nor `$w` is necessary.

That being said, I'd strongly recommend using `Resolve-DnsName` and let that take care of parsing the output for you

```
1..3|%{$p+=Resolve-DnsName "$_.website.com." -Ty TXT -EA 0|% S*s}
```

The `% S*s` command will resolve the `Strings` property on the output records (only property matching the wildcard pattern)